# Bind appsetting.json section to a model with non-public properties or properties with non-matching names

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-6.0, appsettings

.net6 - I have this working fine

```json
{
  "SomeSetting": {
    "A": "value1",
    "B": "value2"
  }
}
```

```cs
internal class MyClass // <-- NOTE, the class is internal
{
    public string A { get; set; } // <-- but property must be public, including public setter
    public string B { get; set; }
}

. . . . .
var inst = config.GetSection("SomeSetting").Get<MyClass>();
```

That works fine ^^.

But it is not binding unless property has name or access level - public. Is it possible to have something like this? --

```cs
internal class MyClass 
{
    internal string A { get; set; } // <-- internal
    internal string B { get; set; }
}
```

or

```cs
internal class MyClass 
{
    public string A { get; internal set; } // <-- internal setter
    public string B { get; internal set; }
}
```

or

```cs
internal class MyClass 
{
    [SomeAttribute()]
    internal string A { get; set; } // <-- internal

    // or
    [SomeOtherAttribute("B")]
    internal string BBB { get; set; } // <-- property name is not matching json file
}
```

I did not look deep into DLLs, I thought that this is JSON binding, so I tried
`using System.Text.Json.Serialization;` `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` `JsonIncludeAttribute`

But so far - no luck

Comment: I'm confused why you don't make them public.  Any type that can see your internal types can also see its internal properties, so how is making the properties internal useful?

Comment: @KirkWoll I want to expose model that has these as Read-only. Right now, anyone who gets access to this model in a consumer assembly can modify the value. Another way is to wrap this model into a read-only model. But right now this is straight curiosity and a learning curve

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Have you [read up on immutability and `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0)?  It should cover your use case.  (For example, by using constructors)

Comment: @KirkWoll Reading right now . . . .

Comment: @KirkWoll cool learning but did not help. In the end, there was a "hidden gem" I did not see from the start. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way. The [immutability with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0) as offered by @KirkWoll (thank you - good learning) did not work. I guess, I can't guarantee that `.Get<MyClass>()` uses that technology. I tried every way described in the document without success.

But there was a simple way, right there. You just create your read-only model like this

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    public string A { get; private set; } 
    public string B { get; private set; }
}
```

and bind it like this - use the additional options

```cs
var inst = config.GetSection("SomeSetting")
    .Get<MyClass>(options => { options.BindNonPublicProperties = true; });
```

This solves the issue of Read-Only model bind to JSON in `IConfiguration`